# Ext JS 6.2.0 Classic - iconCls not works on Chrome

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic, extjs6.2

Despite the same configuration works as expected on Firefox, the icon is not displayed on Chrome.

Here is my `actioncolumn` configuration:

```
xtype       : 'actioncolumn',
width       : 95,
align       : 'center',
sortable    : false,
menuDisabled: true,
items       : [{
    iconCls : 'icon-delete',
    tooltip : 'Delete',
    handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex, node, e, record, rowNode) {
        // delete action
    }
}]
```

Here is the `.css` rules for the `actioncolumn` and the related `iconCls`:

```
.x-action-col-icon {
    color: #919191;
    font-size: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    width: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 1;
}

.icon-delete:before {
    font: 18px/1 FontAwesome;
    color: #dd6550;
    content: "\f056";
}
```

The screenshot for Chrome:

[image]

And for Firefox:

[image]

Comment: Can you put your efforts [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor) ?so I can try to resolved issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2fam), I have checked it and found working fine in both Chrome and Firefox browser.

Note: As of now I have included font-awesome and css (provided by you) in index.html

Screenshots attached:
[image] [image]